# SQL/Python School Program

Tags: python

I have a school project for a Python script which runs an SQL query and spits out results to a file... I have this so far and wanted some feedback on if this looks right or if I am way off (I'm using adodbapi). Thanks much!

```
import adodbapi

# Connect to the SQL DB

conn = adodbapi.connect("Provider=SQLDB;SERVER= x.x.x.x ;User Id=user;Password=pass;DATABASE=db database;")
curs = conn.cursor()

# Execute SQL query test_file.sql"

query = 'test_file'
curs.execute("SELECT test_file")
rows = curs.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print test_file | test_file.txt


conn.close()
```

Comment: Is there a problem or a specific question?

Comment: Yea I was basically look for if it was set up right since it is all using "imaginary" db's when i compile it just says fail to log in so I don't know if the query and on portion work correctly...this is my first venture in py so was looking for some help if this works right

Comment: Looks like you didn't even try to run this. `test_file` will raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `# Execute SQL query test_file.sql"` You are not executing an SQL query from a file. You are executing the SQL query `"SELECT test_file"`.
2. `"SELECT test_file"` is not valid SQL syntax for the `SELECT` query. [See this tutorial on the `SELECT` statement.](http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqlselect.php)
3. `rows = curs.fetchall(); for row in rows: ...` is not a nice way of iterating through all the results of a query.

   - If your query returns  large number of rows, say a million rows, then all one million rows will have to be transferred from the database to your python program before the loop can start. This could be *very* slow if the database server is on a remote machine.
   - Your program will have to allocate memory for the entire data set before work begins. This could be hundreds of megabytes.

The more Pythonic way of doing this is to avoid loading the entire data set into memory unless you have to. Using `sqlite3` I would write:

```
results = curs.execute("SELECT * FROM table_name")
for row in results:
    print (row)
```

This way only one row is loaded at a time.

1. `print test_file | test_file.txt`: the `print` statement does not support the pipe operator for writing to a file. (Python is not a Linux shell!) See [Python File I/O.](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
   Additionally, even if this syntax was correct, you have failed to put the file name in `'quote marks'`. Without quotes, Python will interpret `test_file.txt` as the property `txt` of a variable called `test_file`. This will get you a `NameError` because there is no variable called `test_file`, or possibly an `AttributeError`.

---

If you want to test your code without having to connecting to a network database, then use [the `sqlite3` module](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html). This is a built-in library of Python, implementing a database similar to `adodbapi`.

```
import sqlite3
db_conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:") # connect to temporary database
db_conn.execute("CREATE TABLE colours ( Name TEXT, Red INT, Green INT, Blue INT )")
db_conn.execute("INSERT INTO colours VALUES (?,?,?,?)", ('gray', 128, 128, 128))
db_conn.execute("INSERT INTO colours VALUES (?,?,?,?)", ('blue', 0, 0, 255))
results = db_conn.execute("SELECT * FROM colours")
for row in results:
    print (row)
```

In future please try running your code, or at least testing that individual lines do what you expect. Trying `print test_file | test_file.txt` in an interpreter would have given you a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'`.